# Can't redirect Http to Https nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'v set up a server that run with nginx as reverse proxy for an express app. I want the server to run on https, but when I access it via http, it doesn't redirect to https. Here is my config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.site.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name *.site.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://57.52.110.112:4000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

}
```

I can't find out why this isn't redirecting me to https. How can I make it work? thanks.

Comment: you can see error.log when test, and add error log here

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan , thanks for your reply, i'v checked the error log and i found nothing. It seem it work correctly